# The second child of a second child - Jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors

I wanna know how can I get a value of a child of a child. I have this...

```
<table id="table4">
    <tr>
        <td>Id:</td>
        <td>Name:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1515</td>
        <td>Thiago</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In Jquery, I wanna do something like this...

```
var id = $("#table4:nth-child(2) tr:nth-child(1)").val();
```

How can I do this work? The first `<td>` of the second `<tr>`. I know that I can use "class" and "id" to make it easier, but in this case I can't do that for others reasons.

PS. Sorry about the bad English, I'm a noob in this language.

Thanks.

Comment: Has Orson Scott Card ever coded javascript? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
var id = $("#table4 tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)").text();
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hmfW3/).  The `:nth-child` selector applies *to the child*, for instance the first is saying "a `<tr>` that is a second child of its parent", rather than your attempted version, which would mean "the second child *of* this `<tr>`".

Also, use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get an elements text, rather than [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) which is for input type elements.

Comment: +1, but I think it's probably `:eq` that the OP's actually after.

Comment: @lonesomeday - that would get a *very* specific one (in the set) rather than relative to the row though...depends what the OP is ultimately after I suppose :)

Comment: @lonesomeday: `:eq()` would break the selector for `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a fully jQuery solution, but just thought I'd point out that you could do this:

```
var txt = $("#table4")[0].rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML;
```

Or if there will be any HTML markup you want to avoid, you could do this:

```
var cell = $("#table4")[0].rows[1].cells[0];
var txt = cell.innerText || cell.textContent;
```